# How to iterate over numpy.ndarray which consists of objects? Also apply various functions on them

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have a dataframe of 100000+ rows 
in which I have a column name 'type'
which as unique values like:
`['healer' 'terminator' 'kill-la-kill' 'demonic' 'healer-fpp' 'terminator-fpp' 'kill-la-kill-fpp' 'demonic-fpp']`

What I want is to count the number of each type in the dataframe. What I am doing now to count the row is: 
`len(df.loc[df['type'] == "healer"])`

But in this case I have to write it manually as many times as there are unique values in that column.
Is there any other simpler way to do that?
Also I want to use these condition to filter out other columns as well
like `the 'terminator' killed 78 in the 'kills' and had '0' heals`

Comment: Please post a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy is great, and usually have already a one-liner that covers most requirements like this - I think what you might want is...

```
np.unique(yourArray,  return_counts=True)
```

Which will return a list of unique values, and the number of times each one appears in your array.

try:

```
import numpy as np
np.unique(df['type'].values, return_counts=True)
```

Or, roll it up in a dict, so you can extract the counts keyed by value:

```
count_dict = dict(zip(*np.unique(df['type'].values, return_counts=True)))
count_dict["healer"]

>> 132
```

Then you can plug that into a format string and (assuming you make a similar dictionary called `heals_dict`) do something like:

```
for k in count_dict.keys():
    print ( "the {k} killed {kills} in the 'kills' and had {heals} heals".format(k=k, kills=count_dict[k], heals=heals_dict[k]) )
```

Comment: thanks! It worked. Now how will I get the values of other column based on the obtained value
for example : I need to get the value of `kills` (which is other column) of the type `terminator`

Comment: OK, that's a slightly different operation, since instead of counting up things that have the same value, you're next looking to aggregate (sum?) values held in a separate column, based on the value found in the first.

The simplest way to do this might be to build a pivot table, consisting of the aggregations you intend to perform. 

This for example will sum up all 'kills' and 'heals' columns grouped on the value in the 'type' column:
`df.pivot_table(index='type', values=['kills','heals'], aggfunc=sum)`

But you're probably better off searching/asking a separate question for that.

Answer (score 2):

use value_counts?

```
df['type'].value_counts()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over unique values directly by using `df["type"].unique()`

```
for val in df["type"].unique():
    print(val, len(df[df["type"] == val]))
```